# Copy input field from one to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

UPDATE: I got in contact with the developer and he said to use this code as a foundation:

```
(function($) {

   $('.jr-page').on('keyup','.jrAutoSuggest',function(){
      $(".customfield").val($(this).val());
   });

})(jQuery);
```

It doesn't work at the moment and I'm not sure why but you can also see my original post below this text for more details and I appreciate all of your help:

I am trying to copy one input field to another when a user types.  I would like to accomplish something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bxHQ5/  Notice that when you type into the input box on the left, it duplicates the text on the right.

To be more specific, on my website, I am using [this form](http://www.forzazone.com/forza-car-designs-and-paint-jobs/forza-motorsport-4-car-designs-and-paint-jobs/new-listing_c66/)

I want what the user types in the "Car Manufacturer" input box to directly be copied to the "Testfield" input box as they type.  Also, the "Testfield" input box text cannot be deleted or altered by the user once text is inputted in the car manufacturer field.  They both have to be exactly the same.

Please note that the car manufacturer input field shows a hidden input which the user cannot see and should be ignored in this case.  If you look at the HTML, the car manufacturer input looks like this:

```
<input id="myrelatedfield" class="jrAutoSuggest ui-autocomplete-input acInstructions" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"></input>
```

You'll notice I put my own customer ID in there called "myrelatedfield"  The field it needs to copy text to looks like this which has a custom class "jr_testfield"...

```
<input class="jr_testfield jrText" type="text" data-click2add="0" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_testfield]"></input>
```

Thanks!

Comment: and you have attempted ? you have no code showing you tried to tackle this problem

Comment: u an make other textbox readonly so no-one can edit it..and it will replicate same data too.. http://jsfiddle.net/bxHQ5/382/

Comment: You can see my code here...apologies for not posting it earlier and I appreciate your help!  http://www.forzazone.com/forza-car-designs-and-paint-jobs/forza-motorsport-4-car-designs-and-paint-jobs/new-listing_c66/  As you can see, it is still not working...maybe it is a jquery conflict or something?

Answer (score 2):

I ave updated the code

have a look at it

http://jsfiddle.net/vishalgupta358/bxHQ5/383/

```
$("#EmailAddress").keyup(function(){
    $("#Username").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `disabled` will make the input not submit when the form is submitted. `readonly` may be a better choice here.

Comment: or you can try using `keypress` function. the difference is in 'keypress' as and when you type in the text field it will appear in the adjacent textbox, in 'keyup` you will see the content ,only after you release the key, so there is a slight delay. Use what suits your need.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I used the code in my <head> and it is not working.  Maybe a jquery conflict?  You can see it here: http://www.forzazone.com/forza-car-designs-and-paint-jobs/forza-motorsport-4-car-designs-and-paint-jobs/new-listing_c66/

Comment: Also, in case I didn't say it before, I really appreciate your help with this everyone!

Comment: Please see my post above for an update on this.  I got in contact with the developer of the Joomla component and he provided me with some code that needs tweeking that you see above.  I appreciate all of your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Use `readonly="true"` property to prevent write access.Input value will also be available when u submit the form

HTML:

```
<input type="text"id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" value="" >
 <input type="text" id="Username" readonly="true" name="Username" value="">
```

Script:

```
$("#EmailAddress").keyup(function(){
    $("#Username").val($(this).val());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/bxHQ5/385/)

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Please see my post above for an update on this.  I got in contact with the developer of the Joomla component and he provided me with some code that needs tweeking that you see above.  I appreciate all of your help with this!